Size of the functor category
Let $\mathscr C$, $\mathscr D$ be categories. It's well-known that if both are small, then the functor category $\mathscr D^{\mathscr C}$ is also small. However, it seems to me that we can weaken smallness of $\mathscr D$ to just local smallness. I reason as follows.
For any two functors $F, G\colon \mathscr{C\to D}$, a natural transformation $F\Rightarrow G$ is specified by a family from the product $\prod_{A\in\operatorname{Obj}(\mathscr C)}\mathscr D(FA, GA)$, which is small since $\mathscr D$ is locally small and $\mathscr C$ has a set worth of objects. Thus, each $\mathscr D^{\mathscr C}(F, G)$ is small. Now, $\operatorname{Mor}(\mathscr D^{\mathscr C})$ is just the union of $\mathscr D^{\mathscr C}(F, G)$ as $F$ and $G$'s vary. Thus, all that remains to be shown is that there are a set worth of functors $\mathscr{C\to D}$. Indeed, such a functor is specified by a family from the product $\prod_{f\in\operatorname{Mor}(\mathscr C)}\mathscr D(\operatorname{dom}f, \operatorname{codom} f)$, which is also small as $\mathscr D$ is locally small and $\operatorname{Mor}(\mathscr C)$ is small.
Is my reasoning correct?

What does $\mathscr{D}(\operatorname{dom} f, \operatorname{codom}f)$ mean? $\operatorname{dom} f$ is an object in $\mathscr{C}$.

@Trebor Oops, my bad. Lemme see if I can get around that

Downvoters: This is a perfectly good question. Just because the reasoning is incorrect, doesn't mean it is appropriate to downvote. If people knew the correct reasoning they wouldn't need to ask at all.

You did correctly show that $\mathscr{D}^\mathscr{C}$ is locally small. However, as @Trebor already pointed out, the final part of your argument, intended to show $\mathscr{D}^\mathscr{C}$ has a set worth of objects, is incorrect. This cannot be fixed as the result is wrong. Indeed, just take $\mathscr{C}$ to be the category of a single object with only the identity morphism, and $\mathscr{D}$ be any locally small but not small category (say, $\mathbf{Set}$). Then $\text{Obj}(\mathscr{D}^\mathscr{C})$ is naturally in bijection with $\text{Obj}(\mathscr{D})$, which is a proper class.

@DavidGao This is an answer to the question, not just a comment. Comments should only be used to clarify, not answer the question. See How do comments work for more information.

The category $Set = Set^1$ is of the form $D^C$, with $C$ small and $D$ locally small; it is not small. What is true is that for $C$ small, $D$ locally small, $D^C$ is locally small.
In case you wonder, $D^C$ in case $C,D$ are both locally small doesn't exist (=it exists in a larger universe); what exists is the category of small functors from $C$ to $D$ https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/small+presheaf (the definition can be given more generally than for presheaves)
Ooops, I was about to hit send, and someone commented essentially the same!
